# Multiple SEO phrases in the Search Description of a Blogger blog post

Tags: seo, blogger

This is the search description text box that is visible on the right side of a blog post in edit mode.

---

[image: An image of Search Descriptions text box]

---

Is it possible to include multiple SEO phrases in the Search Description text box? I tried to find information related to this, none of the results I found showed this with multiple search description phrases.

I am trying to find out if doing something like this is possible:

---

[image: An image of Search Descriptions text box with multiple values]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blogger, you can only have one Search Description/meta description per post. And that's okay - in 2009, Google announced that meta description tags (which are what the Blogger Search Descriptions map to) [aren't used as search engine ranking factors](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html). (Neither are meta keywords, for that matter.)

So adding multiple descriptions won't help you here. What *will* help you is writing concise ([< 155 characters](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/meta-description)), compelling description content that will help convince a user to click through to your page from the search engine results page.

If someone searches for a specific keyword, Google may **bold it** if it's included in the Search Description for your post. But again, that won't do anything to help you rank - it'll just help someone know that your blog post is relevant to their keyword search, and thus convince them to click.

So it's not so much search engine optimization you're after here - it's clickthrough optimization.

Answer (score 1):

One Blog Post might have only one Search Description and that seems quite logical as well. Search description is the content that appears along with the title and link when search engine returns results for your search query. So write your search description adequate and concise enough staying brief at the same time so that it gives a complete overview of the blog post it highlights. Search Descripion is a unique piece of text containing abot 150 or so words. You cannot possibly have two descriptions for one post in that word limit.

Search descrption or Meta description is different from search tags or meta tags. You can have multiple meta tags which are infact the different queries people enter in the search engine when searching for a particular thing. The example you have given here, they are not  meta descriptions, rather they are the meta tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as many phrases as you like - but make sure that they end up as one readible paragraph which is in sensible English.  Write for readers, not search-engines, and SEO will look after itself.